# elements are being added to every row when inserting into a row for a 2D array that has been filled with empty Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I am creating a new matrix where I want to take the rows of the original matrix and make them into columns as well as take the columns of the original matrix and make them into rows.

A matrix of:

```
[[1,2]             
 [3,4]             [[1,3,5]
 [5,6]] turns into  [2,4,6]]
```

When I initialize the new matrix while using the fill() method to create my rows, the insertions duplicate for every row when inserting into a row.

```
const arrOne = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

var transpose = function(matrix) {
    const transposedArr = new Array(matrix[0].length).fill(new Array()); // initializes array to [ [], [], [] ]
        
    //iterate through row
    for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {        
        //iterate through columns at row
        for(let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            transposedArr[j].push(matrix[i][j])
        }
    }
    return transposedArr;
};
console.log(transpose(arrOne));
```

This will print

```
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
]
```

When I initialize my array using a for loop, I do not get duplicate entries

```
const arrOne = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

var transpose = function(matrix) {
    const transposedArr = [] // initializing using const transposedArr = Array() also works!
    for(let i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) { // initializes array to [ [], [], [] ]
        transposedArr.push(new Array())
    } 
        
    //iterate through row
    for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {        
        //iterate through columns at row
        for(let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            transposedArr[j].push(matrix[i][j])
        }
    }
    return transposedArr;
};
console.log(transpose(arrOne));
```

This will print:

```
[ 
 [ 1, 4, 7 ],
 [ 2, 5, 8 ],
 [ 3, 6, 9 ] 
]
```

**ASK**: Why is it that when I initialize the array using the fill() method, it is duplicating my insertions for each row?

I came across this issue when working on this Leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/transpose-matrix/

I also tested this code in repl. It was to make sure it wasn't an issue in Leetcode's environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
/* Allocate newMatrix array */
const newMatrix = [];
for (const i in matrix) {
    const temp = [];
    for (const j in matrix[i])
        temp.push(matrix[j][i]);

    newMatrix.push(temp);
}
console.log(newMatrix);
```

First of all, I have created and new array with the opposite length from the **first array** `(Rows = Cols / Cols = Rows)`.

Then you just have to initialize the **second array** with `[i][j] = [j][i]` so it will initialize the column of the original matrix to the row of the new one.

Hope you understood.

By the way fill method "fills" the array element to a STATIC value, and the parameters should be (value, start, end).

Documentation: [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: Thanks for linking the documentation! It's super helpful in understanding why that has happened. It says "If the first parameter is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object" `// A single object, referenced by each slot of the array:
let arr = Array(3).fill({}) // [{}, {}, {}]
arr[0].hi = "hi"            // [{ hi: "hi" }, { hi: "hi" }, { hi: "hi" }]`